# add variable field value to output file name

Tags: export-to-excel

I have a db that imports files in to temp tables prior to exporting the data to excel and appending the temp data to the main table. Each of the files loaded to the temp tables had a column with the same unique value for each record. I would like to create a query to used to filter on the first and add that value from the query to my file naming convention for the person that has to work the output files.

I've created the query that filters on the first but I am not able to find a way to incorporate that result into the file naming for the output.

Function Export_2nd_Level_Excel()

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "2ndLevel", "\pbfsvr01\pbf\PharmNetwork\Audits_Pharmacy\Provider_Audits\Completed Audit files\2nd_Level\" & "[Insert NPI]" & Format(Now, "_ddmmmyy""_2ndLevel_to_PharmAudit") & ".xlsx", True

End Function

I would like to have the "[Insert NPI]" be the actual value from the query that pulls the first of NPI.

Answer (score 0):

after playing around with this for quite some time, I was able to make this work

Function Export_2nd_Level_Excel()

Set db = CurrentDb
Set recd = db.OpenRecordset("2nd_level_NPI")

Dim NPI As String

recd.MoveFirst
NPI = recd![NPI]

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "2ndLevel", "\pbfsvr01\pbf\PharmNetwork\Audits_Pharmacy\Provider_Audits\Completed Audit files\2nd_Level\" & NPI & Format(Now, "_ddmmmyy""_2ndLevel_to_PharmAudit") & ".xlsx", True

End Function